# Auditing my customers paid services

Tags: sql

Hello I am looking at one table here to run a query against.
The tables is similar as below:

```
Name   Item
jon    x
jon    y
mike   x
mike   c
```

I have a list of products that I will be searching for on customers account but I also need to make sure they have another product.
So for instance I need to find all customers who have product x but not product y. 
Or I could be looking for product x or y on a customers account and making sure they have product a and b as well. I have a list of multiple products and corresponding products that should basically of tagged along, what is the simplest way to write this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be a complex nested select statements with **exist** statements and **where** clauses
for example
retrieving names who have item **x** but not have item **y**:

```
 select name,item from table_name
  where item='x' and name not in ( select name from table_name
  where item='y')
```